# deleting row in second page of pagination using reactJS throws error

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, pagination

```html
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { snapshotActions } from '../_actions';
import { organizationActions } from '../_actions';
import { businessunitActions } from '../_actions';
import { lineofbusinessActions } from '../_actions';
import { AlertDismissable } from '../_components';
import {ConfirmModal} from '../_components';
import { FormattedDate, FormattedRelative, FormattedNumber, FormattedMessage, intlShape, injectIntl, defineMessages} from 'react-intl';

const cellEditProp = {
  mode: 'click',
  blurToSave: true
};

class ListSnapshotsPage extends React.Component {

 constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
        row: [],
        sortName: undefined,
        sortOrder: undefined,
        isModalOpen: false
     };

     this.onRowSelect = this.onRowSelect.bind(this);
     this.onSortChange = this.onSortChange.bind(this);
     this.onAllSelect = this.onAllSelect.bind(this);
     this.renderShowsTotal = this.renderShowsTotal.bind(this) ;
     this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
     this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
     this.getNames = this.getNames.bind(this);
    }

 componentDidMount() {
  this.props.dispatch(snapshotActions.getAllSnapshots());
        this.props.dispatch(organizationActions.getAllOrganizations());
        this.props.dispatch(businessunitActions.getAllBusinessUnits());
        this.props.dispatch(lineofbusinessActions.getAllLinesOfBusiness());
  $(".alert-dismissable").hide();
    }


  handleDeleteSnapshot(ids) {
  var names = [] ;
  for(var i = 0 ; i < this.state.row.length ; i++ ) {
   names.push(this.state.row[i].name) ;
  }
  this.state.row = [];
  // this.props.dispatch(snapshotActions.deleteSnapshot(snapshots));
  this.props.dispatch(snapshotActions.deleteSnapshotByName(names));
  this.setState({ isModalOpen: false })
  //setTimeout(function(){ window.location.reload(); }, 3000);
  //setTimeout(function(){ snapShotDisplayData.push(snapData);  }, 3000);
    }

 format(cell, row) {
  let name = ""  ;
  if(cell) {
   name = cell.name;
  }
     return name ;
 }

 
 
 organizationValidator(value, row) {
  if(value == null) {
   return 'Organization Required!';
  } 
    return true;
 }

 createCustomButtonGroup(props) {
  var role = this.props.user.role.name;
  if(role == 'superuser' || role == 'admin' || role == 'manager') {
    return (
       <ButtonGroup className='my-custom-class' sizeClass='btn-group-md'>
            { props.deleteBtn }
       </ButtonGroup>
   );
  }
 }

    createCustomSearchField(props) {
        <FormattedMessage id="listsnapshots.search_field" defaultMessage="Search... " description="Snapshot list search field placeholder"/>
        var searchFieldText = this.props.intl.formatMessage({id: "listsnapshots.search_field"});
 
        return (
          <SearchField
            placeholder={ searchFieldText }/>
        );
      }

    createCustomDeleteButton(){
        <FormattedMessage id="listsnapshots.list_button_delete" defaultMessage="Delete " description="Snapshot list button Delete"/>
        var deleteButtonText = this.props.intl.formatMessage({id: "listsnapshots.list_button_delete"});
 
            return (
                  <DeleteButton
                      btnText={deleteButtonText}
                    // btnContextual='btn-danger'
                      // className='btn btn-danger react-bs-table-del-btn '
                      // btnGlyphicon='fa glyphicon glyphicon-trash fa-trash'
                      // onClick={ this.customConfirm(onBtnClick) }
                  />
              );
       }
    
    openModal() {
        this.setState({ isModalOpen: true })
    }

    closeModal() {
        this.setState({ isModalOpen: false })
    }

    acceptDelete(next) {
        this.handleDeleteSnapshot(next) ;
    }

    getNames() {
        let snapshotNames = []  ;
        for(var i =0; i< this.state.row.length; i++) {
            snapshotNames.push(this.state.row[i].name) ;
        }
        let sNames = snapshotNames.join(',') ;

        return ' '+sNames + '?';
    }
    
    customConfirm(next, dropRowKeys) {
        
        const fadeIn = this.state.open ? 'in' : '';
        const display = this.state.open ? 'block' : 'none';
        var selectStyle = {
            backgroundColor: "white"
        } ;

        this.setState({ isModalOpen: true }) ;
    }

 onRowSelect(row, isSelected, e) {
     if(isSelected) {
      this.state.row.push(row);
     } else {
      for(var i =0; i< this.state.row.length;) {
       if(this.state.row[i].name == row.name) {
        this.state.row.splice(i,1) ;
        i = 0 ;
       } else {
        i++;
       }
      }
     }
 }

 onAllSelect(isSelected, rows, e) {
     if(isSelected) {
      this.state.row = rows;
     } else {
      this.state.row = [];
     }
 }

 onSortChange(sortName, sortOrder) {
     this.setState({
        sortName,
        sortOrder
     });
   }

   remote(remoteObj) {
     // Only cell editing, insert and delete row will be handled by remote store
     remoteObj.cellEdit = true;
     remoteObj.insertRow = true;
     remoteObj.dropRow = true;
     return remoteObj;
   }

   customSort(a, b, order, field) {
    var fieldA = "" ;
    var fieldB = "" ;
    if(field == 'managers') {
   fieldA = a[field][0].firstName ;
     fieldB = b[field][0].firstName ;
    } else {
     fieldA = a[field].name ;
     fieldB = b[field].name ;
    }
  if (order === 'desc') {
      if (fieldA > fieldB) {
          return -1;
      } else if (fieldA < fieldB) {
         return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    }
    if (fieldA < fieldB) {
      return -1;
    } else if (fieldA > fieldB) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
 }

 renderShowsTotal(start, to, total) {
     <FormattedMessage id="listsnapshots.list_from" defaultMessage="From " description="Snapshot list from text"/>
        var fromText = this.props.intl.formatMessage({id: "listsnapshots.list_from"});

        <FormattedMessage id="listsnapshots.list_to" defaultMessage=" to " description="Snapshot list to text"/>
        var toText = this.props.intl.formatMessage({id: "listsnapshots.list_to"});

        <FormattedMessage id="listsnapshots.list_of" defaultMessage=" of " description="Snapshot list of text"/>
        var ofText = this.props.intl.formatMessage({id: "listsnapshots.list_of"});
     return (
        <div style={ { color: 'black', fontSize: 20 } }>
             {fromText} { start } {toText} { to }  {ofText} { total }
        </div>
     );
    }

    render() {
        const propTypes = {
            intl: intlShape.isRequired,
        };


     const selectRowProp = {
   mode: 'checkbox',
   onSelect: this.onRowSelect,
   onSelectAll: this.onAllSelect,
   bgColor: 'lightsteelblue',
   clickToSelect: true  // enable click to select
  };

        const { user, users, snapshots, organizations, businessunits, linesofbusiness} = this.props;

        const snapshotData = snapshots.items ? snapshots.items : [] ;


  let options = {} ;
  if(snapshotData) {
         options = {
    onDeleteRow: this.handleDeleteSnapshot.bind(this),  // A hook for after droping rows.
      btnGroup: this.createCustomButtonGroup.bind(this),
      handleConfirmDeleteRow: this.customConfirm.bind(this),
      sortName: this.state.sortName,
         sortOrder: this.state.sortOrder,
         onSortChange: this.onSortChange, 

         page: 1,  // which page you want to show as default
    sizePerPageList: [ {
        text: '5', value: 5
    }, {
        text: '10', value: 10
    }, {
       text: '25', value: 25
    }, {
        text: 'All', value: snapshotData.length
    } ], // you can change the dropdown list for size per page
    sizePerPage: 10,  // which size per page you want to locate as default
    pageStartIndex: 1, // where to start counting the pages
    paginationSize: 5,  // the pagination bar size.
    prePage: 'Prev', // Previous page button text
    nextPage: 'Next', // Next page button text
    firstPage: 'First', // First page button text
    lastPage: 'Last', // Last page button text
    paginationShowsTotal: this.renderShowsTotal,
    deleteBtn: this.createCustomDeleteButton.bind(this),
                searchField: this.createCustomSearchField .bind(this),
   };
  }

  let organizationOptions = organizations.items && organizations.items.map(organization => (
   { name: organization.name, id: organization.id }
     ));

  var role = this.props.user.role.name;
     var editable = (role == 'superuser' || role == 'admin') ;
     var orgEdit = editable ? { type: 'select', validator: this.organizationValidator.bind(this) }: false ;
     // var departmentEdit  = editable ? { validator: this.departmentValidator.bind(this) }: false ;

     let defaultOrg = {} ;
        if(role != 'superuser') {
         defaultOrg = { name: user.organization.name, id: user.organization.id } ;
        }

        let snapShotDisplayData = [] ;
        if(businessunits.items && linesofbusiness.items) {
      for(var i=0; i < snapshotData.length ; i++) {
       let snap = snapshotData[i] ;

    let level =  snap.level;
       let levelId = snap.levelId
       let levelString =  'CallCenter' ;
       if( level == 2) {
        for(var buIdx = 0; buIdx < businessunits.items.length; buIdx++) {
         let bu = businessunits.items[buIdx]  ;
         if(levelId = bu.id) {
          levelString =  'Business Unit (' + bu.name + ')' ;  
         }
        }
       } else if (level == 3) {
        for(var lobIdx = 0; lobIdx < linesofbusiness.items.length; lobIdx++) {
         let lob = linesofbusiness.items[lobIdx]  ;
         if(levelId = lob.id) {
          levelString =  'Line Of Business (' + lob.businessunit.name + ' -> ' + lob.name + ')' ;  
         }
        }
       }

       let snapData = {
        id    : snap.id,
        name   : snap.name,
        level       : levelString,
        callcenter  : snap.callcenter.name,
        teams   : snap.teams
    }
    snapShotDisplayData.push(snapData);       
      }
     }
        
        <FormattedMessage id="listsnapshots.delete_title" defaultMessage="Delete Snapshot" description="Snapshot list delete Confirm Dialog"/>
        var deleteNameText = this.props.intl.formatMessage({id: "listsnapshots.delete_title"});

        <FormattedMessage id="listsnapshots.delete_message" defaultMessage="Are you sure you want to delete Snapshot - " description="Snapshot list delete message"/>
        var deleteText = this.props.intl.formatMessage({id: "listsnapshots.delete_message"});
        
        let confirmModal = <ConfirmModal 
            isOpen = { this.state.isModalOpen } 
            onOpen = {() => this.getNames() }
            onClose={() => this.setState({ isModalOpen: false }) }
            onAccept={() => this.acceptDelete() }
            validateState={ false }
            ignoreEditable={ false }
            nameText={ deleteNameText }
            deleteText={deleteText}
            dispatch={this.props.dispatch }/>

        return (
         <div>
          <div className="wrapper">
           <div className="content-wrapper">
                        {confirmModal}
            {snapshots.loading && <div className="loader"></div>}
            {snapshots.error && <AlertDismissable alertprops={{content:snapshots.error, bsStyle: "danger" }} />}
            {snapshots.success && <AlertDismissable alertprops={{content:snapshots.success, bsStyle: "success" }} />}
            <section className="content-header">
       <h1>
                    <FormattedMessage id="listsnapshots.list_title" defaultMessage="Snapshots" description="Snapshots header greeting" />
       </h1>
       <ol className="breadcrumb">
        <li><i className="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <FormattedMessage id="listsnapshots.breadcrumb_home" defaultMessage="Home" description="Snapshot list breadcrumb Home" /></li>
        <li className="active"><FormattedMessage id="listsnapshots.breadcrumb_snapshot_configuration" defaultMessage="Snapshots" description="Snapshots breadcrumb" /></li>
       </ol>
      </section> 
             <section className="content">
              <BootstrapTable className="table" style={ {marginTop: '150px'} } remote={ this.remote } pagination={ true } search={ true }  multiColumnSearch={ true } cellEdit={ cellEditProp } data={snapShotDisplayData} insertRow={ true } deleteRow={ true } selectRow={ selectRowProp } options={ options } striped hover>
               <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField='id' editable={ false } hidden = {true} hiddenOnInsert={ true } autoValue={ true } >
                        <FormattedMessage id="listsnapshots.list_id" defaultMessage="Id" description="snapshot list Id table header" />
                    </TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn autoFocus dataSort editable={ false } dataField='name' editable={ false }>
                        <FormattedMessage id="listsnapshots.list_snapshot" defaultMessage="Snapshot Name" description="snapshot list name table header" />
                       </TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn autoFocus dataSort editable={ false } dataField='callcenter' editable={ false }>
                        <FormattedMessage id="listsnapshots.list_callcenter" defaultMessage="Call Center" description="snapshot list Call Center table header" />
                       </TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn autoFocus dataSort editable={ false } dataField='level' editable={ false }>
                        <FormattedMessage id="listsnapshots.list_level" defaultMessage="Level" description="snapshot list Level table header" />
                       </TableHeaderColumn>
          {/*
          <TableHeaderColumn autoFocus dataSort editable={ false } dataField='teamName' editable={ false }>Team Name</TableHeaderColumn>
          */}

       </BootstrapTable>
                </section>
              </div>
           }
          </div>
            </div>
        );
        ListSnapshotsPage.propTypes = propTypes; 
    }
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
    let returnObj = {}

 const { users, organizations, snapshots, authentication, businessunits, linesofbusiness} = state;
 const { user } = authentication;
    
    returnObj = { user, users, snapshots, organizations, businessunits, linesofbusiness }; 

   return returnObj ;
}

const connectedListSnapshotsPage = connect(mapStateToProps)(injectIntl(ListSnapshotsPage));
export { connectedListSnapshotsPage as ListSnapshotsPage };
```

am using reactJs with pagination, here if second page has only row, when i tried to delete that row its throws error like

```
> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`  at TableBody.eval (TableBody.js?975a:246)
```

Comment: can you add code snippet?

Comment: added, check once @Harish

Comment: You're trying to render an element that's no longer there, this will also happen if you have only one element on the first page and delete that. When deleting elements, check if there are any elements left for that page, if not you go back one page.